# Sending AppleEvent fails with sandbox

Tags: swift, nsapplescript

I try to show an element in the Calendar.app so the calendar is activated and the appropriate event is highlighted. I know how to do that but once Sandbox is on, I just get

> Calendar got an error: A privilege violation occurred.

My code simply is this (not even trying to show an event but just reading one calendar):

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let source = "tell application \"iCal\"\n set theCalendar to first calendar whose name = \"test\"\nend tell"
    let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: source)
    var errorDict: NSDictionary? = nil
    _ = scriptObject!.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)
    print (errorDict)
  }
}
```

And my Entitlements look like that:

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.ical</key>
    <array>
      <string>com.apple.ical.read</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

I also tried with scripting bridge but that fails too (with less information but probably the same reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure of the entitlement `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` in Calendar.app seems to be a bug (even using `tell application "Calendar"` in the script).

However the global temporary exception works:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
  <string>com.apple.ical</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Wow. I made a quick test, but only with my reduced example and that seems to to the trick. I'll try that with the full version right now.

Comment: Very cool. Especially the fact that Apple's so-called "support" did not point me in that direction but let me starve with my support request for more than 3 years. Thank you very much!!